# "itk::ERROR: GeodesicActiveContourLevelSetImageFilter(000002189D4F4460): Inputs do not occupy the same physical space! "

Tags: python, image-segmentation, itk

I'm trying to segment an object in an image using ITK's GeodesicActiveContourLevelSetImageFilter. My code is almost identical to the example in https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Segmentation/LevelSets/SegmentWithGeodesicActiveContourLevelSet/Documentation.html, and yet I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: c:\p\ipp\standalone-build\itk-source\modules\core\common\include\itkImageToImageFilter.hxx:241:
itk::ERROR: GeodesicActiveContourLevelSetImageFilter(000002189D4F4460): 
Inputs do not occupy the same physical space! 
InputImage Direction: -1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00
0.0000000e+00 -1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00
0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 -1.0000000e+00, 
InputImageInitialImage Direction: 1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00
0.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00
0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00

Tolerance: 1.0000000e-06
```

It seems like the (NifTi) image's direction changes after CurvatureAnisotropicDiffusionImageFilter - I think it is mirrored at this stage, for some reason. The error is triggered at "writer.Update()" (please see my code attached below).

This is my first experience in ITK, I would appreciate your help.

```
initialDistance = 0.0
sigma = 0.5
alpha = -0.3
beta = 2.0
propagationScaling = 10.0
numberOfIterations = 400
seedValue = -initialDistance

Dimension = 3
InputPixelType = itk.F
OutputPixelType = itk.UC
InputImageType = itk.Image[InputPixelType, Dimension]
OutputImageType = itk.Image[OutputPixelType, Dimension]

ReaderType = itk.ImageFileReader[InputImageType]
WriterType = itk.ImageFileWriter[OutputImageType]

reader = ReaderType.New()
reader.SetFileName(inputFileName)

SmoothingFilterType = itk.CurvatureAnisotropicDiffusionImageFilter[InputImageType, InputImageType]
smoothing = SmoothingFilterType.New()
smoothing.SetTimeStep(0.0625)
smoothing.SetNumberOfIterations(5)
smoothing.SetConductanceParameter(1.5)
smoothing.SetInput(reader.GetOutput())

GradientFilterType = itk.GradientMagnitudeRecursiveGaussianImageFilter[InputImageType, InputImageType]
gradientMagnitude = GradientFilterType.New()
gradientMagnitude.SetSigma(sigma)
gradientMagnitude.SetInput(smoothing.GetOutput())

SigmoidFilterType = itk.SigmoidImageFilter[InputImageType, InputImageType]
sigmoid = SigmoidFilterType.New()
sigmoid.SetOutputMinimum(0.0)
sigmoid.SetOutputMaximum(1.0)
sigmoid.SetAlpha(alpha)
sigmoid.SetBeta(beta)
sigmoid.SetInput(gradientMagnitude.GetOutput())

FastMarchingFilterType = itk.FastMarchingImageFilter[InputImageType, InputImageType]
fastMarching = FastMarchingFilterType.New()

GeoActiveContourFilterType = itk.GeodesicActiveContourLevelSetImageFilter[InputImageType, InputImageType, InputPixelType]
geodesicActiveContour = GeoActiveContourFilterType.New()
geodesicActiveContour.SetPropagationScaling(propagationScaling)
geodesicActiveContour.SetCurvatureScaling(1.0)
geodesicActiveContour.SetAdvectionScaling(1.0)
geodesicActiveContour.SetMaximumRMSError(0.02)
geodesicActiveContour.SetNumberOfIterations(numberOfIterations)
geodesicActiveContour.SetInput(fastMarching.GetOutput())  
geodesicActiveContour.SetFeatureImage(sigmoid.GetOutput())

ThresholdingFilterType = itk.BinaryThresholdImageFilter[InputImageType, OutputImageType]
thresholder = ThresholdingFilterType.New()
thresholder.SetLowerThreshold(-1000.0)
thresholder.SetUpperThreshold(0.0)
thresholder.SetOutsideValue(itk.NumericTraits[OutputPixelType].min())
thresholder.SetInsideValue(itk.NumericTraits[OutputPixelType].max())
thresholder.SetInput(geodesicActiveContour.GetOutput())

seeds = itk.VectorContainer[itk.UI, itk.LevelSetNode[InputPixelType, Dimension]].New()
seeds.Initialize()
for i in range(len(seedsCoords[0])): # seedCoords are supplied from another func in the form of ([x coordinates], [y coordinates], [z coordinates])
    seedPosition = itk.Index[Dimension]()
    seedPosition[0] = int(seedsCoords[0][i])
    seedPosition[1] = int(seedsCoords[1][i])
    seedPosition[2] = int(seedsCoords[2][i])

    node = itk.LevelSetNode[InputPixelType, Dimension]()
    node.SetValue(seedValue)
    node.SetIndex(seedPosition)
    seeds.InsertElement(0, node)

fastMarching.SetTrialPoints(seeds)
fastMarching.SetSpeedConstant(1.0)

CastFilterType = itk.RescaleIntensityImageFilter[InputImageType, OutputImageType]

caster1 = CastFilterType.New()
caster2 = CastFilterType.New()
caster3 = CastFilterType.New()
caster4 = CastFilterType.New()
#
writer1 = WriterType.New()
writer2 = WriterType.New()
writer3 = WriterType.New()
writer4 = WriterType.New()

caster1.SetInput(smoothing.GetOutput())
writer1.SetInput(caster1.GetOutput())
writer1.SetFileName("GeodesicActiveContourImageFilterOutput1.png")
caster1.SetOutputMinimum(itk.NumericTraits[OutputPixelType].min())
caster1.SetOutputMaximum(itk.NumericTraits[OutputPixelType].max())
writer1.Update()

caster2.SetInput(gradientMagnitude.GetOutput())
writer2.SetInput(caster2.GetOutput())
writer2.SetFileName("GeodesicActiveContourImageFilterOutput2.png")
caster2.SetOutputMinimum(itk.NumericTraits[OutputPixelType].min())
caster2.SetOutputMaximum(itk.NumericTraits[OutputPixelType].max())
writer2.Update()

caster3.SetInput(sigmoid.GetOutput())
writer3.SetInput(caster3.GetOutput())
writer3.SetFileName("GeodesicActiveContourImageFilterOutput3.png")
caster3.SetOutputMinimum(itk.NumericTraits[OutputPixelType].min())
caster3.SetOutputMaximum(itk.NumericTraits[OutputPixelType].max())
writer3.Update()

caster4.SetInput(fastMarching.GetOutput())
writer4.SetInput(caster4.GetOutput())
writer4.SetFileName("GeodesicActiveContourImageFilterOutput4.png")
caster4.SetOutputMinimum(itk.NumericTraits[OutputPixelType].min())
caster4.SetOutputMaximum(itk.NumericTraits[OutputPixelType].max())
fastMarching.SetOutputSize(reader.GetOutput().GetBufferedRegion().GetSize())

writer = WriterType.New()
writer.SetFileName(outputFileName)
writer.SetInput(thresholder.GetOutput())
writer.Update()  # triggers the error

print(
    "Max. no. iterations: " +
    str(geodesicActiveContour.GetNumberOfIterations()) + "\n")
print(
    "Max. RMS error: " +
    str(geodesicActiveContour.GetMaximumRMSError()) + "\n")
print(
    "No. elpased iterations: " +
    str(geodesicActiveContour.GetElapsedIterations()) + "\n")
print("RMS change: " + str(geodesicActiveContour.GetRMSChange()) + "\n")

writer4.Update()

InternalWriterType = itk.ImageFileWriter[InputImageType]

mapWriter = InternalWriterType.New()
mapWriter.SetInput(fastMarching.GetOutput())
mapWriter.SetFileName("GeodesicActiveContourImageFilterOutput4.mha")
mapWriter.Update()

speedWriter = InternalWriterType.New()
speedWriter.SetInput(sigmoid.GetOutput())
speedWriter.SetFileName("GeodesicActiveContourImageFilterOutput3.mha")
speedWriter.Update()

gradientWriter = InternalWriterType.New()
gradientWriter.SetInput(gradientMagnitude.GetOutput())
gradientWriter.SetFileName("GeodesicActiveContourImageFilterOutput2.mha")
gradientWriter.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ITK are you using? Have you tried the latest stable release (4.13.1) or a recent master?

Does the problem occur with the unmodified example? If it doesn't, comparing the differences should lead you to solution.

If none of this solves the issue, can you share the input image? Or better yet, a crop of the input image which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi Dženan, thanks for your answer. I am using version 4.13.1 of ITK, and the problem does not occur with the example code and input. I ran the code over only one slice of the original image to check the conversion to 3D - it works only if I insert the data as a .png file (giving the same NifTi that generated the .png generates the same propblem). As for sharing the image I'm working on, I'll have to check whether that's possible since it is medical data.

Comment: Then the problem seems to be in the Nifti metadata. Taking the image header and making the content all zeroes would probably be enough to reproduce the problem? You can use a hex editor to zero out the content.

Comment: Here is a link to the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogwrlqjgun88icw/2_data.nii?dl=0 I  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a bug in one of the filters, which does not respect/propagate orientation (also known as direction). It could very well be the `CurvatureAnisotropicDiffusionImageFilter`. You input image looks like it has inverted unit direction (identity matrix with -1s instead of 1s), and some filter ignores that and outputs identity orientation. Please report it at http://issues.itk.org